# Kotlin infix operator on nullable property objects

Tags: kotlin

When I have a kotlin class like this:

```
class Test (
    val param1 : Long,
    val param2 : Long
)

class EqualityExpr<T: Any> (
    val lhs : KProperty<T>,
    val rhs : KProperty<T>
)

infix fun <T: Any> KProperty<T>.equals(KProperty<T> rhs) : EqualityExpr<T> {
    return EqualityExpr(this, rhs)
}
```

The expression `Test::param1 equals Test::param2` works just fine and calls the infix function. However when I do this:

```
class Test (
    val param1 : Long?,
    val param2 : Long?
)
```

The same expression fails. What is the type of these nullable properties if not a subclass of `KProperty<*>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call doesn't work on the nullable property because you're expecting the `rhs` parameter to have the same `T` type parameter as the receiver of your extension, which it doesn't. One of them Is a `KProperty<Long>`, while the other one is a `KProperty<Long?>`, and `Long?` can't be inferred for `T` because of the non-nullable `Any` upper bound.

```
val kProperty1: KProperty<Long> = Test::param1
val kProperty2: KProperty<Long?> = Test::param2
```

One way to make the call work would be to allow the `T` type parameter to be nullable, if that works for you:

```
class EqualityExpr<T : Any?> (
        val lhs: KProperty<T>,
        val rhs: KProperty<T>
)

infix fun <T : Any?> KProperty<T>.equals(rhs: KProperty<T>): EqualityExpr<T> {
    return EqualityExpr(this, rhs)
}
```

With this change, the `kProperty1 equals kProperty2` call makes sense, because `Long?` is inferred as the type parameter, and both properties are of the type `KProperty<Long?>`.

Comment: Also of interest here to anyone who follows, apparently `Any` is not covariant with `Any?` like he said, but `Any` can be implicitly cast to `Any?`. The `Any?` version of the function @zsmb13 wrote ended up also accepting a `KProperty<Long>`  as well as `KProperty<Long?>`